# Keeping a session when using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, session-cookies

In my project I'm using C# app client and tomcat6 web application server.
I wrote this snippet in the C# client:

```
public bool isServerOnline()
{
        Boolean ret = false;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(VPMacro.MacroUploader.SERVER_URL);
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                ret = true;
            }
            resp.Close();
            return ret;

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // Exception - connection not available
            Log.e("InternetUtils - isServerOnline - " + we.Status);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Everytime I invoke this method, I get a new session at server side. 
I suppose it's because I should use HTTP cookies in my client. But I don't know how to do that, can you help me?

Comment: Good question! Transferring sessions have kept me awake allot in the past

Comment: And do you solved this issue?

Comment: I used Guillaume suggestion back then

Comment: Ok, but how I can manage expired cookie? Is it automatically with CookieContainer?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must use a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) and keep the instance between calls.

```
private CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
public bool isServerOnline()
{
        Boolean ret = false;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(VPMacro.MacroUploader.SERVER_URL);
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer; // <= HERE
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                ret = true;
            }
            resp.Close();
            return ret;

        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // Exception - connection not available
            Log.e("InternetUtils - isServerOnline - " + we.Status);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it and let you know if this works. But I've a question: if cookie expired how can I manage this?

Comment: Another question, but I shouldn't get the Cookie from the response?

Comment: The container will be filled, you don't have to care about response cookie. Also the size of the container is limited and when the limit is reached, expired cookies are removed.

Comment: ASP. Net mvc is a server side framework. The cookie container is client side. So yes it will work regardless of server side stack as long as cookies are used

Comment: can i use this method to preserve basic authentication session? Also can i use same cookie container instance for several different username and password pairs?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili basic authentication relies on Authorization HTTP header, not cookies. You'll have to keep sending this header on every request. Feel free to post a question if you need more help.