# Visual Studio reading session value and storing into a string

Tags: php, session, visual-studio-2013, captcha

I am working on my captcha and also doing a bypass for it. The form is on form.php and the captcha is made through php's imagettftext function.

The string of the captcha is stored in a session called 'string'. I need to get the value of that session into a variable in visual studio.

```
var strMy = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("string");
```

That is what I have tried but I get an error on HttpContext.

So in summary, I need to get the value of a string that is stored on image.php into a variable in visual studio.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might need to open a connection to your site and keep the connection open while you query the server for the current session. Looks like it's already been asked & answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275616/keeping-a-session-when-using-httpwebrequest

Comment: Thanks but I am very new to Visual Studio, is there anyway you could provide me a code? I've got almost no idea about how to use that code.